Excel VBA Code: Consolidate in a single row all similar Items in specific columns and concatenate other details in a single cell
1
Above screenshot is my current output but I'm not sure how can I change the output to the screenshot below:

For this instance Ingredient "Onions" in the first screenshot it is places in multiple rows, and now I want to be the output like in the 2nd screenshot where the Ingredient "Onions" is now in a single row but the other columns is being concatenated like in Meal Type and Particular column.
Below is my current VBA Code:
Sub FilterAndCopyData()
    Dim wsMenu As Worksheet
    Dim wsDishes As Worksheet
    Dim wsIngredients As Worksheet
    Dim wsTemp As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowDishes As Long
    Dim lastRowIngredients As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim results As Collection
    ' Set references to the worksheets
    Set wsMenu = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Menu")
    Set wsDishes = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dishes Database")
    Set wsTemp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Market List")
    ' Check if Ingredient Database sheet exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsIngredients = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ingredients Database")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wsIngredients Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Worksheet 'Ingredient Database' not found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    
        ' Clear specified ranges in "Market List"
    With Sheets("Market List")
        .Range("H4:H8").ClearContents
        .Range("E10:I16").ClearContents
        .Range("C20:I24").ClearContents
        .Range("C29:I33").ClearContents
        .Range("C38:I42").ClearContents
    End With
    
    ' Copy data from "Menu" and paste it into "Market List"
    With Sheets("Menu")
        .Range("F6:F8").Copy
    End With
    
    With Sheets("Market List")
        .Range("H4:H6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
    
    ' Clear the clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    ' Copy meal data based on conditions
    Dim mealData As Range
    Set mealData = Sheets("Menu").Range("D11", Sheets("Menu").Range("D11").End(xlDown))

    Dim mealCell As Range
    Dim breakfast As String, amSnacks As String, lunch As String
    Dim pmSnacks As String, cocktails As String, dinner As String, midnight As String

    breakfast = ""
    amSnacks = ""
    lunch = ""
    pmSnacks = ""
    cocktails = ""
    dinner = ""
    midnight = ""

    For Each mealCell In mealData
        Select Case mealCell.Value
            Case "AM Snacks"
                If amSnacks <> "" Then amSnacks = amSnacks & ", "
                amSnacks = amSnacks & mealCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Case "Breakfast"
                If breakfast <> "" Then breakfast = breakfast & ", "
                breakfast = breakfast & mealCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Case "Lunch"
                If lunch <> "" Then lunch = lunch & ", "
                lunch = lunch & mealCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Case "PM Snacks"
                If pmSnacks <> "" Then pmSnacks = pmSnacks & ", "
                pmSnacks = pmSnacks & mealCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Case "Cocktails"
                If cocktails <> "" Then cocktails = cocktails & ", "
                cocktails = cocktails & mealCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Case "Dinner"
                If dinner <> "" Then dinner = dinner & ", "
                dinner = dinner & mealCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Case "Midnight"
                If midnight <> "" Then midnight = midnight & ", "
                midnight = midnight & mealCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End Select
    Next mealCell

    ' Replace empty strings with "None"
    If amSnacks = "" Then amSnacks = "None"
    If breakfast = "" Then breakfast = "None"
    If lunch = "" Then lunch = "None"
    If pmSnacks = "" Then pmSnacks = "None"
    If cocktails = "" Then cocktails = "None"
    If dinner = "" Then dinner = "None"
    If midnight = "" Then midnight = "None"
        ' Paste the concatenated meal data into "Market List"
        With Sheets("Market List")
            .Range("E10").Value = amSnacks
            .Range("E11").Value = breakfast
            .Range("E12").Value = lunch
            .Range("E13").Value = pmSnacks
            .Range("E14").Value = cocktails
            .Range("E15").Value = dinner
            .Range("E16").Value = midnight
        End With
        
        
    ' Find the last row with data in Column B of Dishes Database sheet
    lastRowDishes = wsDishes.Cells(wsDishes.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    ' Find the last row with data in Column A of Ingredient Database sheet
    lastRowIngredients = wsIngredients.Cells(wsIngredients.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ' Initialize the collection to store the results
    Set results = New Collection
    ' Loop through each value in Menu Column C11, D11, E11, and F8 onwards
    For i = 11 To wsMenu.Cells(wsMenu.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        Dim menuValueC As Variant
        Dim menuValueD As Variant
        menuValueC = wsMenu.Cells(i, "C").Value
        menuValueD = wsMenu.Cells(i, "D").Value
        ' Loop through each value in Menu Column E11 onwards
        For j = 11 To wsMenu.Cells(wsMenu.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
            Dim menuValueE As Variant
            menuValueE = wsMenu.Cells(j, "E").Value
            ' Loop through Dishes Database to find matching values
            For k = 6 To lastRowDishes
                If wsDishes.Cells(k, "A").Value = menuValueC And wsDishes.Cells(k, "B").Value = menuValueE Then
                    ' Find corresponding values in Ingredient Database
                    Dim dishName As String
                    dishName = wsDishes.Cells(k, "C").Value
                    ' Search for dishName in Ingredient Database
                    Dim l As Long
                    For l = 4 To lastRowIngredients
                        If wsIngredients.Cells(l, "A").Value = dishName Then
                            ' Add unique results to the collection
                            Dim key As String
                            key = dishName & "_" & menuValueD & "_" & menuValueE
                            On Error Resume Next
                            results.Add Array(dishName, wsDishes.Cells(k, "D").Value, wsIngredients.Cells(l, "C").Value, wsIngredients.Cells(l, "D").Value, menuValueD, menuValueE, wsIngredients.Cells(l, "B").Value), key
                            On Error GoTo 0
                            Exit For ' Exit inner loop once a match is found
                        End If
                    Next l
                End If
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
    
    ' Write the results to Market List starting from row 2
    Dim resultRow As Long
    
    
    Dim m As Long
    Dim colMarketList As Integer
    Dim dblSubtotal As Double
    Dim dblGrandTotal As Double
    
    resultRow = 18 'reference row for Market List start or items
    
    ' Clear previous data in Market List starting from row 2
    wsTemp.Rows(resultRow & ":" & wsTemp.Rows.Count).Clear
    colMarketList = 2
    
    ' Create the Headers
    ' MEAT AND SEAFOOD
    With wsTemp
        .Range("A" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
        .Range("K" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
    End With
    wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 1).Value = "MEAT AND SEAFOOD"
    With wsTemp.Range(wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 1).Address & ":" & wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 7).Address)
        .Interior.Color = RGB(175, 169, 170)
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
    
    resultRow = resultRow + 1
    With wsTemp
        .Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 1).Value = "Ingredients"
        .Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 2).Value = "Quantity"
        .Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 3).Value = "UoM"
        .Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 4).Value = "Cost per Unit"
        .Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 5).Value = "Total Cost"
        .Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 6).Value = "Meal Type"
        .Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 7).Value = "Particular"
    End With
    With wsTemp.Range(wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 1).Address & ":" & wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 7).Address)
        .Interior.Color = RGB(226, 239, 218)
    End With
    With wsTemp
        .Range("A" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
        .Range("K" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
    End With
    
    resultRow = resultRow + 1
    For m = 1 To results.Count
        If results(m)(6) = "MEAT AND SEAFOOD" Then
            wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 1).Value = results(m)(0) ' Dish Name from Dishes Database
            wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 2).Value = results(m)(1) * Sheets("Market List").Range("H6").Value ' Ingredient Column D from Ingredient Database
            wsTemp.Range(wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 2).Address).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
            wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 3).Value = results(m)(2) ' Ingredient Column C from Ingredient Database
            wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 4).Value = results(m)(3)  ' Column D from Dishes Database"
            
            wsTemp.Range(wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 5).Address).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
            wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 5).Formula = Replace("=D{var}*F{var}", "{var}", CStr(resultRow))
            
            'wsTemp.Range(wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 5).Address).Formula = Replace("=D{var}*F{var}", "{var}", resultRow) ' Column D from Dishes Database"
            wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 6).Value = results(m)(4) ' Menu Column D value
            wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 7).Value = results(m)(5) ' Menu Column E11 onwards value
            
            With wsTemp.Range(wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 1).Address & ":" & wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 7).Address).Borders
                .LineStyle = 1
                .Color = RGB(115, 114, 112)
            End With
            With wsTemp
                .Range("A" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
                .Range("K" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
            End With
            
            dblSubtotal = dblSubtotal + wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 5)
            resultRow = resultRow + 1
        End If
    Next m
    
    wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 4).Value = "Subtotal"
    wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 5).Value = dblSubtotal
    wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 5).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    dblGrandTotal = dblGrandTotal + dblSubtotal
    With wsTemp
        .Range("A" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
        .Range("K" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
    End With
    resultRow = resultRow + 1
    With wsTemp
        .Range("A" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
        .Range("K" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
    End With
    resultRow = resultRow + 1
    With wsTemp
        .Range("A" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
        .Range("K" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
    End With
    
    ' Create the Headers
    ' VEGETABLES AND FRUITS
    wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 1).Value = "VEGETABLE AND FRUITS"
    With wsTemp.Range(wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 1).Address & ":" & wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 7).Address)
        .Interior.Color = RGB(175, 169, 170)
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
    
    resultRow = resultRow + 1
    With wsTemp
        .Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 1).Value = "Ingredients"
        .Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 2).Value = "Quantity"
        .Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 3).Value = "UoM"
        .Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 4).Value = "Cost per Unit"
        .Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 5).Value = "Total Cost"
        .Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 6).Value = "Meal Type"
        .Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 7).Value = "Particular"
    End With
    With wsTemp.Range(wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 1).Address & ":" & wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 7).Address)
        .Interior.Color = RGB(226, 239, 218)
    End With
    With wsTemp
        .Range("A" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
        .Range("K" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
    End With
    
    resultRow = resultRow + 1
    For m = 1 To results.Count
        If results(m)(6) = "VEGETABLE AND FRUITS" Then
            wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 1).Value = results(m)(0) ' Dish Name from Dishes Database
            wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 2).Value = results(m)(1) * Sheets("Market List").Range("H6").Value ' Ingredient Column D from Ingredient Database
            wsTemp.Range(wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 2).Address).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
            wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 3).Value = results(m)(2) ' Ingredient Column C from Ingredient Database
            wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 4).Value = results(m)(3)  ' Column D from Dishes Database"
            
            wsTemp.Range(wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 5).Address).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
            wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 5).Formula = Replace("=D{var}*F{var}", "{var}", CStr(resultRow))
            
            'wsTemp.Range(wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 5).Address).Formula = Replace("=D{var}*F{var}", "{var}", resultRow) ' Column D from Dishes Database"
            wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 6).Value = results(m)(4) ' Menu Column D value
            wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 7).Value = results(m)(5) ' Menu Column E11 onwards value
            
            With wsTemp.Range(wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 1).Address & ":" & wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 7).Address).Borders
                .LineStyle = 1
                .Color = RGB(115, 114, 112)
            End With
            With wsTemp
                .Range("A" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
                .Range("K" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
            End With
            
            dblSubtotal = dblSubtotal + wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 5).Value
            resultRow = resultRow + 1
        End If
    Next m

    wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 4).Value = "Subtotal"
    wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 5).Value = dblSubtotal
    wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 5).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    dblGrandTotal = dblGrandTotal + dblSubtotal
    With wsTemp
        .Range("A" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
        .Range("K" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
    End With
    resultRow = resultRow + 1
    With wsTemp
        .Range("A" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
        .Range("K" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
    End With
    resultRow = resultRow + 1
    With wsTemp
        .Range("A" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
        .Range("K" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
    End With
    
    ' Create the Headers
    ' GROCERY ITEMS
    wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 1).Value = "GROCERY ITEMS"
    With wsTemp.Range(wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 1).Address & ":" & wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 7).Address)
        .Interior.Color = RGB(175, 169, 170)
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
    
    resultRow = resultRow + 1
    With wsTemp
        .Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 1).Value = "Ingredients"
        .Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 2).Value = "Quantity"
        .Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 3).Value = "UoM"
        .Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 4).Value = "Cost per Unit"
        .Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 5).Value = "Total Cost"
        .Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 6).Value = "Meal Type"
        .Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 7).Value = "Particular"
    End With
    With wsTemp.Range(wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 1).Address & ":" & wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 7).Address)
        .Interior.Color = RGB(226, 239, 218)
    End With
    With wsTemp
        .Range("A" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
        .Range("K" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
    End With
    
    resultRow = resultRow + 1
    For m = 1 To results.Count
        If results(m)(6) = "GROCERY ITEMS" Then
            wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 1).Value = results(m)(0) ' Dish Name from Dishes Database
            wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 2).Value = results(m)(1) * Sheets("Market List").Range("H6").Value ' Ingredient Column D from Ingredient Database
            wsTemp.Range(wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 2).Address).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
            wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 3).Value = results(m)(2) ' Ingredient Column C from Ingredient Database
            wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 4).Value = results(m)(3)  ' Column D from Dishes Database"
            
            wsTemp.Range(wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 5).Address).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
            wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 5).Formula = Replace("=D{var}*F{var}", "{var}", CStr(resultRow))

            
            'wsTemp.Range(wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 5).Address).Formula = Replace("=D{var}*F{var}", "{var}", resultRow) ' Column D from Dishes Database"
            wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 6).Value = results(m)(4) ' Menu Column D value
            wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 7).Value = results(m)(5) ' Menu Column E11 onwards value
            
            With wsTemp.Range(wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 1).Address & ":" & wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 7).Address).Borders
                .LineStyle = 1
                .Color = RGB(115, 114, 112)
            End With
            With wsTemp
                .Range("A" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
                .Range("K" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
            End With
            
            dblSubtotal = dblSubtotal + wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 5).Value
            resultRow = resultRow + 1
        End If
    Next m
    
    wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 4).Value = "Subtotal"
    wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 5).Value = dblSubtotal
    wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 5).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    dblGrandTotal = dblGrandTotal + dblSubtotal
    With wsTemp
        .Range("A" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
        .Range("K" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
    End With
    resultRow = resultRow + 1
    With wsTemp
        .Range("A" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
        .Range("K" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
    End With
    resultRow = resultRow + 1
    With wsTemp
        .Range("A" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
        .Range("K" & resultRow).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 255, 153)
    End With
    wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 4).Value = "Grand Total"
    wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 5).Value = dblGrandTotal
    wsTemp.Cells(resultRow, colMarketList + 5).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    
       
    ' Navigate to "Market List" worksheet
    wsTemp.Activate
    MsgBox "Data copied successfully to Market List.", vbInformation
End Sub


Your question is not so clear, at least for me... 1. You show pictures of two ranges and your code uses three sheets. Which of them to be the pictures you show, without naming the sheets belonging to. 2. You show ranges without columns labels, so we have to follow and deduce this aspect from your code, even if you suggest that it does not work as you need... 3. Your above picture is output of what? Which to be the bases to be processed? If we intend helping, what to use from your question as range to be processed? Should we read your code and understand it, even if it is wrong?

You can easily solve this using Power Query (available since Excel 2010). You Merely have to group by Ingredient, then aggregate any resultant columns. And you can start with your original data, not the pre-processed screen shot.

You did not answer my clarification questions... So, in the next piece of code I will try showing how to transform the first picture content in the second one. It uses a dictionary (to firstly determine the unique ingredients and their corresponding elements) and arrays to let the code working only in memory and being fast. Please, **take care to adapt the returning sheet with an appropriate one. Now, it returns in the next sheet (against the active one). The code assumes that the range to be processed starts from "A1" in the active sheet.:
Sub UniqueIngredientsCumullative()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, wsRet As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrIt, arrFin
 Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, dict As Object
 
 Set ws = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
 Set wsRet = ws.Next 'use here your sheet where to return the processed result
 lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 
 arr = ws.Range("A2:G" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster processing
 
 'load the dictionary:
 Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'set the necessary dictionary
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then 'if the dictionary key does not exist
        ReDim arrIt(5)                 'redim the intermediary array
        For j = 0 To UBound(arrIt): arrIt(j) = arr(i, j + 2): Next j 'load the data in the array
        dict.Add arr(i, 1), arrIt      'place the array as dictionary item
    Else
       Erase arrIt 'clear the array (also redimmed dimensions...)
       arrIt = dict(arr(i, 1)) 'extract the array item, to be modified
       'process the rest of array elements as described in your question:
       arrIt(0) = arrIt(0) + arr(i, 2): arrIt(2) = arrIt(2) + arr(i, 4)
       arrIt(3) = arrIt(3) + arr(i, 5): arrIt(4) = arrIt(4) & ", " & arr(i, 6)
       arrIt(5) = arrIt(5) & ", " & arr(i, 7)
       dict(arr(i, 1)) = arrIt 'place back the modified array as dict item
    End If
 Next i
 
 'place the dictionary data in the final array (arrFin):
 ReDim arrFin(1 To dict.count, 1 To UBound(arr))
 For i = 0 To dict.count - 1 'iterate between the dictionary elements (base 0)
    k = k + 1                     'initialize and increment the array rows
    arrIt = dict.Items()(i)       'extract the dict item in an array, to be processed
    arrFin(k, 1) = dict.keys()(i) 'place the key in the first  final array column
    For j = 0 To UBound(arrIt): arrFin(k, j + 2) = arrIt(j): Next j 'place the next items on the next columns
 Next i
 
 'Drop the final array content, at once:
 wsRet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value2 = arrFin
 
 MsgBox "Ready...": wsRet.Activate
End Sub

Please, send some feedback after testing it.
